# Parametrized tests in Angular

Tags: .net, angular, testing, nunit

Is there any way to build parametrized tests in Angular2? I mean something similar to for instance nUnit TestCase attribute in .NET.

https://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5

I'm trying to test a few example values in the same situation without writing the same code 5 or 6 times.